# Can not figure out Javas strings?

Tags: java

I am a student at the moment so I am still learning. I picked up VB pretty quick and it was simple Java on the other hand I am pretty confused on.

The Assignment I have been given this time has me confused "Write a method to determine the number of positions that two strings differ by. For Example,"Peace" and "Piece" differ in two positions. The method is declared int compare(String word1, String word2); if the strings are identical, the method returns 0. It returns -1 if the two strings have different lengths."

Additional "Write a main method to test the method. The main method should tell how many, positions the strings differ, or that they are identical, or if they are different lengths, state the lengths. Get the strings from the console.
So far this is where I am at and I am looking for someone to help break this down in I DUMDUM terms if they can I don't need a solution only help understanding it.

```
package arraysandstrings;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class differStrings {
    public static void main (String agrs[]){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word");
        String word1;
        String word2;
        word1 = scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Enter another word");
        word2 = scanner.next();
        int count = 0;
        int length = word1.length();

        for(int x = 0; x >= length; x = x+1) {
            if (word1.charAt(x) == word2.charAt(x)) {
                count = count + 1;
                System.out.print (count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additional Question

```
   package arraysandstrings;
   import java.util.Scanner;

 public class differStrings {
 public static void main (String agrs[]){
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter a word");
 String word1 = scanner.next();

System.out.println("Enter another word");
String word2 = scanner.next();
int count = 0;
int word1Length = word1.length();
int word2Length = word2.length();

if (word1Length != word2Length) {
      System.out.println ("Words are a diffrent length");
      System.out.println (word1 + "Has" + word1.length() + " chars");
      System.out.println (word2 + "Has" + word2.length() + " chars");
}

for(int x = 0; x < word1Length; x = x+1) {

       if (word1.charAt(x) != word2.charAt(x)) {
        count = count + 1;
       }}}

 System.out.println (count+" different chars");
```

}

After implementing the knowledge Iv gained from your responses I have ran in to a problem with the last line:

```
 System.out.println (count+" different chars");
```

It says Error  expected however it worked before I added the next part of my assignment which was this:

```
   if (word1Length != word2Length) {
      System.out.println ("Words are a diffrent length");
      System.out.println (word1 + "Has" + word1.length() + " chars");
      System.out.println (word2 + "Has" + word2.length() + " chars");
}
```

Comment: You are counting the places were the character are the same with `if (word1.charAt(x) == word2.charAt(x))` don't you want `if (word1.charAt(x) != word2.charAt(x))`?

Comment: You are absolutely right I was trying t get the opposite of what I needed. Thanks a lot I am making the correction now.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong with the code, it was that the system.out.print statement I move outside of the method brackets (my appologies for any incorrect terminology)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int x = 0; x >= length; x = x+1) {
```

You probably mean

```
for(int x = 0; x < length; x = x+1) {
```

Comment: I made that change right away, however it does not print out "count" on the console for some reason I will look to see if the syntax is wrong and Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a loop which compares the two strings and counts the places where they are not equal.

Your logic counts the number of places where the two characters are the same.  You are also printing the count each time the two characters are equal.

What it sounds like you need is a loop that iterates over the characters in the two strings comparing each character and incrementing the count of mis-matched or different characters.  Then after getting a count of different characters by comparing all of the characters, you would print out the count of different characters.

So the basics would be: (1) read each of the strings, (2) check that the lengths are the same, (3) if same length then loop over the string comparing each character and incrementing the count of mis-matched characters each time there is a difference, (4) print out the count.  If the string lengths are different then just set the count to negative one (-1) and do not bother to compare the two strings.

What would be kind of neat to do is to create a string of underscores and asterisk, in which each matching character position is represented by an underscore and each mis-matching character position is represented by an asterisk or perhaps the string would contain all of the matching characters and the mis-matching characters would be replaced by an asterisk.

**Edit: adding example program**

The example below is an annotated rewrite of your program.  One change that I made was to use a function to perform the counting of the non-matching characters.  The function, `countNonMatchChars ()` is a static function in order to work around the object oriented nature of Java.  This function is a utility type function and not really part of a class.  It should be available to anyone who wants to use it.

Also rather than incrementing variables with the syntax of `var = var + 1;` I instead use the postincrement operator of ++ as in `var++;`.

```
package arraysandstrings;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class so_strings_main {

    // function to compare two strings and count the number
    // of characters that do not match.
    //
    // this function returns an integer indicating the number
    // of characters that did not match or a negative one if the
    // strings are not equal in length.
    //
    // "john"  "john"   returns 0
    // "john1" "john2"  returns 1
    // "mary1" "john1"  returns 4
    // "john"  "john1"  returns -1 (lengths are not equal)
    public static int countNonMatchChars (String s1, String s2)
    {
        // initialize the count to negative one indicating strings unequal in length
        // get the lengths of the two strings to see if any comparison is needed
        int count = -1;
        int word1Length = s1.length();
        int word2Length = s2.length();

        if (word1Length == word2Length) {
            // the lengths of the two strings are equal so we now do our comparison
            // we start count off at zero.  as we find unmatched characters, we
            // will increment our count.  if no unmatched characters found then
            // we will return a count of zero.
            count = 0;
            for(int iLoop = 0; iLoop < word1Length; iLoop++) {
                if (s1.charAt(iLoop) != s2.charAt(iLoop)) {
                    // the characters at this position in the string do not match
                    // increment our count of non-matching characters
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        // return the count of non-matching characters we have found.
        return count;
    }

    public static void main (String agrs[]){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Count non-matching characters in two strings.");
        System.out.println("Enter first word");
        String word1 = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Enter second word");
        String word2 = scanner.next();
        int count = countNonMatchChars (word1, word2);

        if (count < 0) {
            System.out.println ("Words are a diffrent length");
            System.out.println ("   " + word1 + " Has " + word1.length() + " chars");
            System.out.println ("   " + word2 + " Has " + word2.length() + " chars");
        } else {
            System.out.println (count + " different chars");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you explaining that to me, the book I have is about as clear as mud.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting around some code, adding some line breaks and making 2 small tweaks to the logic produces a program that is closer to what you are trying to build.

```
package arraysandstrings;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class differStrings {
  public static void main (String agrs[]){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word");
    String word1 = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Enter another word");
    String word2 = scanner.next();
    int count = 0;
    int length = word1.length();

    for(int x = 0; x < length; x = x+1) {
        if (word1.charAt(x) != word2.charAt(x)) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println (count+" different chars");
  }
}
```

It looks like in addition to the for loop that @LouisWasserman pointed out you had code that was trying to find characters that are the same.

Comment: There are still other aspects of your question that this does not address (like strings of different lengths), but this should put you on the right path.

Comment: You guy are great I cant tell you how hard Iv been stressing trying to understand this quickly, and the responses on this site are EXTREMELY quick and helpful. To be honest I was expecting to get yelled at for asking a newby question on an expert site.  Thanks to all of you for the help.

Comment: I think on balance people here are supportive of people who want to learn. Honestly I tend to go months between asking a question because every time I start to I see someone else has already asked it and received great feedback.

Comment: Once again I really do appreciate it!